# Why isn't css calc function working properly in Chrome on Android

Tags: css

I have the following little snippet of CSS;

```
ul#list li div.column {
    width: -moz-calc(40% - 12px);
    width: -o-calc(40% - 12px);
    width: -webkit-calc(40% - 12px);
    width: calc(40% - 12px);
}
```

This works as expected in Chrome on iPad, iPhone, and OSX but on Chrome for Android (4.2.2 on a Google Nexus 7) it is giving a width that is far too short. I don't have dev tools set up to query the device to see what is going on but this is driving me insane. Is there a known bug with this browser?

Comment: Which browser version? See [**this**](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell. I've never used an Android device before today and can't see any version info in Chrome.

Comment: I would like to suggest setting your phone up to work with the Chrome debug tools. You can hook your phone to your computer and use the full developer tools Chrome makes available. It's pretty easy to setup too.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you've already figured out, calc is not supported on Android. Best resource that I've found to determine whether a feature is supported is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) - in your case, this should help: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Actually it is supported on Chrome for Android, just not on the version I was using at the time. With a recent Chrome version on my Nexus 7 it is now working just fine.